# Is it possible to use CSOM powershell and pnpsharepoint2013 from desktop?

Tags: 2013, csom, pnp

Environment: SharePoint 2013

Do I need to be on the SharePoint Servers in order to run CSOM and pnp from desktop PC? Can anyone please suggest and a good link. I tried and it's not working.

Kayla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. By name, using CSOM is *Client Side* Object Model. For PnP PowerShell, you need to use this specific version:

```
Install-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShell2013
```

This will install the version meant for 2013. Note that the cmdlets conflict, so you'll want to explicitly load this PoSh module if you have multiple PnP modules installed.